# dovecot can't compact mail folder /var/mail/username

Tags: permissions, mail, dovecot

ubuntu 11.10 32bit.  Setup a dovecot imap server.  Using Thunderbird on a different ubuntu machine (64bit) to access imap server.  Everything else is fine, except I can not compact the deleted email in inbox, which is stored at /var/mail/username.  Checking mail.log and I see this error message:

```
Apr  3 00:10:11 autumn dovecot: imap(username): Error: file_dotlock_create(/var/mail/username) failed: Permission denied (euid=1000(username) egid=1000(username) missing +w perm: /var/mail, euid is not dir owner) (set mail_privileged_group=mail)
```

what is wrong with the permission?  Here are the permissions for the relevant files:

```
$ ls -ld /var/mail
drwxrwsr-x 2 mail mail 4096 2012-04-02 23:36 /var/mail

$ ls -l /var/mail/username
-rw------- 1 username mail 417 2012-04-02 23:36 /var/mail/username
```

Anyone knows what's going on here?

Comment: I went into /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf, added the group mail to the line "mail_privileged_group = ", stop dovecot, and then start dovecot.  It works now.  Although I wish this was documented somewhere.

Comment: It is documented [here](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/mbox). Please convert your comment to an answer and accept it so that this question is not left hanging without an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went into `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`, added the group mail to the line "`mail_privileged_group =` ", stop `dovecot`, and then start `dovecot`. It works now.

As pointed out by Celada, it is documented [here](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/mbox).

Answer (score 1):

I will write as to correct it on steps. I test it Debian 8 and ubuntu server 14.04.

1. `sudo nano /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`
2. change the parameter `#mail_privileged_group` to `mail_privileged_group = mail`
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>
5. `sudo service dovecot restart`
6. Profit!

Comment: This answer should be edited to be completely in English.

Comment: This is the same as [this older answer](/a/118941/175814). Also, please use text to include textual information – not images.